# Status of cron job

Tags: shell, cron

I have written a cron job as follows:
`$crontab -e` 
Then it opened a file where i wrote
`5 * * * * USERNAME PATH-TO-SHELLSCRIPT`
How would i come to know that my job has been executed?

Answer (score 1):

Do something with the script? Edit a file and add timestamp for example to see if its ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a log file. Create a file under your home directory, e.g., "/home/user/.cronlog/script1", and output script execution time and status messages with timestamps. You can then check the logs to see script history. To test your script first execute it every minute. Then change the crontab entry to the actual period.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you understand the time parameters so you know when to expect it to work :)
I use crontab for a 5 min interval cron like this: */5 * * * *

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron